# How do I get rid of Amazon Assistant?

Tags: uninstall, browser, software-uninstall, amazon

I just want to uninstall Amazon Assistant and everything I look up seems to be related to Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon assistant is an extension or addon for the browser ([chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-assistant-for-chro/pbjikboenpfhbbejgkoklgkhjpfogcam) or [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/amazon-browser-bar/)). Open up the extensions or addon page for the browser you use and remove if from there.